# Creating a String with values array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to convert a strings array into an array that counts the occurrences of each string and store it in the new array in the string index.

[a][a][b] will turn into an `array("a" => "2", "b" => "1")

EDIT: I don't know the original array values. I didn't wrote any code yet since I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: use `array_count_values`.for more visit here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
$arr=array("a","a","b");
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [b] => 1
)
```

Comment: I don't know the original array values.

Comment: @ImriPersiado if it is not a multidimensional array above code will work for any array.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) best suits your need ! It does what you need, meaning counting occurences of element in your array, creating another array in result containing for keys the element, and for values the number of this element.

(Exemple taken from PhP documentation)

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

will result in an array containing :

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```